# Unable to Add Column Names in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, data-science

Here's my sample csv file upon printing:

```
  1556890689.332073;16384;340;48188.23529411765;[1618.6294555664062   1619.0826416015625  ...   1620.391845703125.584   1620.1904296874998]
0  1556890689.746113;16384;341;48046.92082111437;...                         1619.082642  ...             1620.442200   1619.6868896484373]
1  1556890690.1393259;16384;340;48188.23529411765...                         1620.643616  ...             1619.888306       1619.384765625]
2  1556890690.536072;16384;340;48188.23529411765;...                         1619.737244  ...             1620.089722    1620.391845703125]
```

I try running this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("project_fan.csv", error_bad_lines = False) 
print(data.head())
data.columns['unixTime', 'sampleAmount','Time','samplingRate', 'Data']
```

and get these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 6, in <module>
    data.columns['unixTime', 'sampleAmount','Time','samplingRate', 'Data']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3969, in __getitem__
    result = getitem(key)
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default separator parameter in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) is `,`, so is necessary add parameter `sep=';'`, for new columns names if not exist in `csv` add parameter `names` with list with same length like number of columns:

```
names = ['unixTime', 'sampleAmount','Time','samplingRate', 'Data']
data = pd.read_csv("project_fan.csv", sep=';', error_bad_lines = False, names=names)
```